# Cant pass php variable into ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a php variable into an ajax function (as below) to dynamically change the url used for the post request but cant seem to get this to work, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
$site_url = "http://www.example.com/";
?>

<script>
    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $site_url ?>';
            dataType: 'json',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data) {
                jQuery("#data").html(data.today_data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The PHP is fine, the problem is the `;` after the `url` property - remove it. For future reference - always check the console when debugging JS. You will have had a syntax error shown with this issue.

Comment: correct remove only semicolon from this - '<?php echo $site_url ?>';

Comment: Legend, thanks, cant believe i missed that!!